# How to get numeric value inside <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to calculate sum of checked tr's.

```
var totalqt=0;
totalqt=totalqt + $(this).closest("tr").find("#qt").text();
```

It gets correct values but doesn't operate with it like digits. for ex, if value was 1 for first td, and 2 for second td, it alerts 12 instead of 1+2. Tried text() and html(). Same result. What's wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by checked tr's, can you post a quick snippet of HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
totalqt = totalqt + parseInt($(this).closest("tr").find("#qt").text(), 10);
```

Comment: It's always worth specifying the base of the parseInt e.g. parseInt(val, 10), otherwise the default assumption can occasionally not be 10 and you can end up with octal values etc.

Comment: You should never have multiple elements with the same ID, so you should just be able to do `$("#qt").text()`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to parse the value as a number this will either be using parseInt(val, base) or parseFloat(val, base):

In your example you'd use:

```
var totalqt=0;
totalqt=totalqt +parseInt( $(this).closest("tr").find("#qt").text(), 10);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse the string to an int so that you can use it like an int.

```
var totalqt=0;
totalqt=totalqt + parseInt($(this).closest("tr").find("#qt").text(), 10);
```

The 10 is because:

> The problem is with how parseInt guesses the base of your number. Read
>   the parseInt spec. Instead of always defaulting to base 10, it tries
>   to guess, and if the first character is '0' it thinks you want to
>   parse as an octal number, and if it starts with '0x' it thinks you
>   want hexadecimal.

Answer (score 2):

`text()` returns a string. You want a number. Use `parseInt`:

```
var totalqt = 0;
totalqt = totalqt + parseInt($(this).closest("tr").find("#qt").text(), 10);
```

Comment: Unlike the other answers this one also uses second parameter that specifies the base in which the number should be converted so this is much safer than other answers.